# Customize the axis label in seaborn jointplot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I seem to have got stuck at a relatively simple problem but couldn't fix it after searching for last hour and after lot of experimenting.

I have two numpy arrays `x` and `y` and I am using seaborn's jointplot to plot them:

```
sns.jointplot(x, y)
```

Now I want to label the xaxis and yaxis as "X-axis label" and "Y-axis label" respectively. If I use `plt.xlabel`, the labels goes to the marginal distribution. How can I make them appear on the joint axes?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`sns.jointplot` returns a [JointGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid) object, which gives you access to the matplotlib axes and you can then manipulate from there.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# example data
X = np.random.randn(1000,)
Y = 0.2 * np.random.randn(1000) + 0.5

h = sns.jointplot(X, Y)

# JointGrid has a convenience function
h.set_axis_labels('x', 'y', fontsize=16)

# or set labels via the axes objects
h.ax_joint.set_xlabel('new x label', fontweight='bold')

# also possible to manipulate the histogram plots this way, e.g.
h.ax_marg_y.grid('on') # with ugly consequences...

# labels appear outside of plot area, so auto-adjust
h.figure.tight_layout()
```

[image: seaborn jointplot with custom labels]

(The problem with your attempt is that functions such as `plt.xlabel("text")` operate on the current axis, which is not the central one in `sns.jointplot`; but the object-oriented interface is more specific as to what it will operate on).

Note that the last command uses the figure attribute of the JointGrid. The initial version of this answer used the simpler - but not object-oriented - approach via the `matplotlib.pyplot` interface.
To use the pyplot interface:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: What is `plt` referring to? That appears to be undefined, and I failed to use `.tight_layout()` on an existing jointplot too.

Comment: @Chrimle I updated the answer so it now uses a method that exists. `plt` is a very common shorthand/alias for `matplotlib.pyplot`, which is the library that seaborn uses underneath for its graphs. But it was lazy not to import it, thanks for the clarifying qu.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can specify the axes labels in a pandas `DataFrame` in the call to `jointplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

x = ...
y = ...
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'X-axis label': x,
    'Y-axis label': y,
})
sns.jointplot(x='X-axis label', y='Y-axis label', data=data)
```

Comment: I would add that you don't even need to explicitly construct the `DataFrame`. You can just pass the dict directly to the `data` `kwarg`!