# How to manually change the tick labels of the margin plots on a Seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jointplot

I am trying to use a log scale as the margin plots for my seaborn jointplot. I am usings set_xticks() and set_yticks(), but my changes do not appear. Here is my code below and the resulting graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
female_waiters = tips[tips['sex']=='Female']

def graph_joint_histograms(df1):
    g=sns.jointplot(x = 'total_bill',y = 'tip', data = tips, space = 0.3,ratio = 3)
    g.ax_joint.cla()
    g.ax_marg_x.cla()
    g.ax_marg_y.cla()

    for xlabel_i in g.ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels():
        xlabel_i.set_visible(False)
    for ylabel_i in g.ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels():
        ylabel_i.set_visible(False)

    x_labels = g.ax_joint.get_xticklabels()
    x_labels[0].set_visible(False)
    x_labels[-1].set_visible(False)

    y_labels = g.ax_joint.get_yticklabels()
    y_labels[0].set_visible(False)
    y_labels[-1].set_visible(False)

    g.ax_joint.set_xlim(0,200)
    g.ax_marg_x.set_xlim(0,200)

    g.ax_joint.scatter(x = df1['total_bill'],y = df1['tip'],data = df1,c = 'y',edgecolors= '#080808',zorder = 2)
    g.ax_joint.scatter(x = tips['total_bill'],y = tips['tip'],data = tips, c= 'c',edgecolors= '#080808')

    ax1 =g.ax_marg_x.get_axes()
    ax2 = g.ax_marg_y.get_axes()
    ax1.set_yscale('log')
    ax2.set_xscale('log')
    
    ax1.set_yscale('log')
    ax2.set_xscale('log')

    ax2.set_xlim(1e0, 1e4)
    ax1.set_ylim(1e0, 1e3)
    ax2.xaxis.set_ticks([1e0,1e1,1e2,1e3])
    ax2.xaxis.set_ticklabels(("1","10","100","1000"), visible = True)


    plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible = True)
    colors = ['y','c']
    ax1.hist([df1['total_bill'],tips['total_bill']],bins = 10, stacked=True,log = True,color = colors, ec='black')

    ax2.hist([df1['tip'],tips['tip']],bins = 10,orientation = 'horizontal', stacked=True,log = True,color = colors, ec='black')
ax2.set_ylabel('')
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here is the resulting graph:

[image]

Comment: You asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266091/how-to-change-the-tick-labels-on-a-a-seaborn-joint-plot) two days ago. I do not think that reposting same questions is a good practice on SO and it will definitely not help you to find an answer.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm trying to improve the question so I made it not reliant on my own dataset and my original question was lacking in detail on the code.

Comment: Then you should update the original question, because there are two ppl already trying to help you there and you can notify them about the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually get an error from the line `g.ax_marg_y.get_axes()` since an axes does not have a `get_axes()` method. 
Correcting for that

```
ax1 =g.ax_marg_x
ax2 = g.ax_marg_y
```

should give you the desired plot. The ticklabels for the log axis are unfortunately overwritten by the histogram's `log=True` argument. So you can either leave that out (since you already set the axes to log scale anyways) or you need to set the labels *after* calling `hist`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

def graph_joint_histograms(tips):
    g=sns.jointplot(x = 'total_bill',y = 'tip', data = tips, space = 0.3,ratio = 3)
    g.ax_joint.cla()
    g.ax_marg_x.cla()
    g.ax_marg_y.cla()

    for xlabel_i in g.ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels():
        xlabel_i.set_visible(False)
    for ylabel_i in g.ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels():
        ylabel_i.set_visible(False)

    x_labels = g.ax_joint.get_xticklabels()
    x_labels[0].set_visible(False)
    x_labels[-1].set_visible(False)

    y_labels = g.ax_joint.get_yticklabels()
    y_labels[0].set_visible(False)
    y_labels[-1].set_visible(False)

    g.ax_joint.set_xlim(0,200)
    g.ax_marg_x.set_xlim(0,200)

    g.ax_joint.scatter(x = tips['total_bill'],y = tips['tip'],data = tips,
                       c = 'y',edgecolors= '#080808',zorder = 2)
    g.ax_joint.scatter(x = tips['total_bill'],y = tips['tip'],data = tips, 
                       c= 'c',edgecolors= '#080808')

    ax1 =g.ax_marg_x
    ax2 = g.ax_marg_y
    ax1.set_yscale('log')
    ax2.set_xscale('log')

    ax2.set_xlim(1e0, 1e4)
    ax1.set_ylim(1e0, 1e3)

    ax2.xaxis.set_ticks([1e0,1e1,1e2,1e3])
    ax2.xaxis.set_ticklabels(("1","10","100","1000"), visible = True)

    plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible = True)
    colors = ['y','c']
    ax1.hist([tips['total_bill'],tips['total_bill']],bins = 10, 
             stacked=True, color = colors, ec='black')

    ax2.hist([tips['tip'],tips['tip']],bins = 10,orientation = 'horizontal', 
             stacked=True, color = colors, ec='black')
    ax2.set_ylabel('')


graph_joint_histograms(tips)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see, thank you for that! Do you know why the tick labels for the y margin plot are not being changed to 1,10,100,1000?